# Cloned Bitnami server sending traffic to wrong site

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, web-server, wordpress, bitnami

I'm sorry if this is something that is obvious or easily obtainable, but I've inherited a project at work and have been given very little time.

We have a Bitnami web server that hosts our main site, our dev server has fallen severely out of date and so to replace it, I did a full clone of the original server with AWS (I did a MySQL backup and a file level backup) and then did the "Make more like this" option in AWS.

It seems to work but when you send traffic to the IP address of the dev site, it sends you to the production .com site instead. (I've checked that its hitting the prod server instead of the dev server)

Any ideas? I tried .htaccess but didn't see anything.

Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. Clone the database
2. Clone the web / wordpress server
3. Edit wp-config.php to point wordpress at the new database

That should do it. If it doesn't you need to provide more information to help with the diagnosis.

Comment: I've never been so happy to see a database error. I can now import the new database and test. Thanks!